# Change the output automatically without refreshing

Tags: javascript, html, refresh, innerhtml

I have this code, it basically changes the word 'article' to 'articles' if the value is '0' or more than '1'. But the word only changes when the page is refreshed. Is it possible to automaticaly re-run the code at the same moment the value (quantity) changes?

```
<span id="quantity" class="simpleCart_quantity"></span> gets it's value from an    external file, it is always a number (like 0, 1, 2, 3, etc.)

<span id="quantity" class="simpleCart_quantity"></span>
<span id="quantityText"></span>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(window).load(function() 
    {
    var quantity = document.getElementById("quantity"),
        quantityText = document.getElementById("quantityText");
    if (parseInt(quantity.innerHTML, 10) === 1) {
        quantityText.innerHTML = "article";
    } else {
        quantityText.innerHTML = "articles";
    }
    });
</script>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How `quantity` changes its value?

Comment: <span id="quantity" class="simpleCart_quantity"></span> gets it's value from an external file, it is always a number (like 0, 1, 2, 3 etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible.

The direct and dirty way is to poll the server for changes at an interval.  make a timer function that calls an ajax function that checks to see if the article count has changed.

something like:

```
setInterval(function(){
        $.ajax({
           url:"checkchanges.php",
           dataType:"json",
           type:'GET',
           .success(function(data){
              if (data.articlecount>1){ //pseudocode, it depends on how you get your data
                  $("#quantity").innerHTML="articles";
              }
            })
        });
    },3000);
```

Another method is to use a framework like meteor that wires the checking up for you.

Comment: thanks! If you have time could you show me how to? I'm sorry.. This is the first time coding in javascript

Comment: @OwenParsons I updated the answer with a sample.  It looked like you were using jquery for the window call and load function, so I went with that.